# How to set default value of a class type parameter in c++?

Tags: c++, class, parameters

In below code snippet i want to set default value of a classA type variable **obj=class(3,5)** in func().How to do it without using pointer?Can you give me an example  with default contructor ?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

 class classA{
     int a,b;
 public:
    classA(int x,int y){a=x;  b=y;  cout<<"contructing........\n";}
    ~classA(){cout<<"destructing........\n";}
    int add(){return a+b;}

 };

void func(classA obj=class(3,5);

int main()
{
    classA obj(5,10);
    func(obj);
    func();
    
}

void func(classA obj=classA(3,5))
{
    int getObjVal;
    getObjVal=obj.add();
    cout<<"\nMultiply returned value with 5 gives: "<<getObjVal*5;
}
```

Comment: typo in declaration should be: `void func(classA obj=classA(3,5));` and in definition default value is not needed. https://godbolt.org/z/rvjKhf

Comment: You can also write `void func(classA obj={3,5});`

Answer (score 1):

For declaration like `classA obj;` default constructor is needed.

The function default argument is provided in declaration and may not be repeated by function definition.

Using in-class member initializers like `int a{}, b{};` the members `a` and `b`  are 0-initialized by default.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

 class classA{
     int a{},b{}; // using {} -> a and b 0-initialized by default
 public:
    classA() = default;
    classA(int x,int y){a=x;  b=y;  cout<<"contructing........\n";}
    ~classA(){cout<<"destructing........\n";}
    int add(){return a+b;}

 };

void func(classA obj=classA(3,5));

int main()
{
    classA obj; // <- default constructor needed here
    func(obj);
    
}

void func(classA obj)
{
    int getObjVal;
    getObjVal=obj.add();
    cout<<"\nMultiply returned value with 5 gives: "<<getObjVal*5;
}
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dfc46d72bbf958f)